# How can I configure ENV values from task AzureFunctionApp in ADO pipeline?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

How can I configure ENV values from task AzureFunctionApp in ADO pipeline?   Basically, when I have a FunctionApp that was created separately from Terraform,  on this task that uploads the .jar file, how can I include some environment variables with the push?

Is this possible?

I tried this, but it doesn't work, and gets a compile error.

```
  - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      appType: 'functionApp'
      appName: 'my-api-$(environment)'
      package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/my-api/my-api-1.0.0'
      runtimeStack: 'JAVA|11'
      configurationStrings:
        - TEST: "what"
```

I also tried this, which compiles and runs, and it didn't work for me either.  The env variable doesn't show up in the app settings after deploy.

```
  - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      appType: 'functionApp'
      appName: 'my-api-$(environment)'
      package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/my-api/my-api-1.0.0'
      runtimeStack: 'JAVA|11'
      appSettings: "-TEST what"
```

Comment: Turns out I need to remove the quotes on that 2nd example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Azure Function App Task Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops), the yaml key that you need is `appSettings`

Try this way:

```
  - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      appType: 'functionApp'
      appName: 'my-api-$(environment)'
      package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/my-api/my-api-1.0.0'
      runtimeStack: 'JAVA|11'
      appSettings: '-MY_ENV_VARIABLE test'
```

Application settings should follow the syntax -key value. Values containing spaces should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: That compiles and runs but the ENV var doesn't show up in my function app.  I'll try without the quotes...

Comment: Yep,  I just need to remove the quotes and it worked!!

Comment: I think it was weird that quotes broke it.  not very logical.